# Export mysql DB to CSV in mysqlworkbench

Tags: mysql, csv, export, mysql-workbench

How can I export all database tables at one time, from mysqlworkbench (or in some other way, if through mysqlworkbench not possible)? I have 30 tables and it is a lot to export each individual table.

Comment: Do you specifically need CSV files or is this just the first thing you thought of

Comment: I specificslly need all tables exported to csv.

Comment: Never actually used this feature, but phpMyAdmin has an options to export as an CSV

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do with phpmyadmin. You can prepare select query as you want and you can export the data in pdf, excel, csv format.